# How do I debug this stacktrace from crashlytics

Tags: ios, flutter, crashlytics

I have this issue on crashlytics

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Flutter                        0x18518 (Missing UUID 4c4c441f55553144a1682f45551c1451)
1  Flutter                        0x1838c (Missing UUID 4c4c441f55553144a1682f45551c1451)
2  Flutter                        0x2ebf8 (Missing UUID 4c4c441f55553144a1682f45551c1451)
3  Flutter                        0x2ed60 (Missing UUID 4c4c441f55553144a1682f45551c1451)
4  UIKitCore                      0x8f240 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1808
5  QuartzCore                     0x1fc20 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 520
6  QuartzCore                     0x1a5348 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 500
7  QuartzCore                     0x32f0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 648
8  AppKit                         0xb05884 __37+[NSDisplayCycle currentDisplayCycle]_block_invoke.7 + 44
9  AppKit                         0xb05cb8 ___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke + 44
10 CoreFoundation                 0x7d894 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28
11 CoreFoundation                 0x7d7a8 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
12 CoreFoundation                 0x7cc3c __CFRunLoopRun + 2440
13 CoreFoundation                 0x7bc5c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
14 HIToolbox                      0x30448 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
15 HIToolbox                      0x30284 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 648
16 HIToolbox                      0x2ffdc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
17 AppKit                         0x39c54 _DPSNextEvent + 660
18 AppKit                         0x80febc -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
19 AppKit                         0x2541ec -[NSApplication _shouldTerminate] + 1124
20 AppKit                         0x246de0 -[NSApplication terminate:] + 856
21 Foundation                     0x78850 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372
22 CoreFoundation                 0x99cd0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
23 CoreFoundation                 0x99978 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 972
24 CoreFoundation                 0x994b0 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 356
25 CoreFoundation                 0x7c9f4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1856
26 CoreFoundation                 0x7bc5c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
27 HIToolbox                      0x30448 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
28 HIToolbox                      0x300d8 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 220
29 HIToolbox                      0x2ffdc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 76
30 AppKit                         0x39c54 _DPSNextEvent + 660
31 AppKit                         0x80febc -[NSApplication(NSEventRouting) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 716
32 AppKit                         0x2d100 -[NSApplication run] + 476
33 AppKit                         0x43cc NSApplicationMain + 880
34 AppKit                         0x257240 _NSApplicationMainWithInfoDictionary + 22
35 UIKitMacHelper                 0x4d8c UINSApplicationMain + 972
36 UIKitCore                      0x393c UIApplicationMain + 148
37 Runner                         0x879c main + 5 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
38 ???                            0x1852310e0 (Missing)
```

There's some things missing and I'm not sure how to fix that, because my dysm are being uploaded by flutterfire cli

The issue seems to only appear on `iPad Pro (12.9-inch, 3rd generation)` running `macOS 17.1.0`, which I presume means that it's an M series mac, and it only happens in the background.

Does anybody know how I can debug this?